# img tag in monaca project

Tags: angular, monaca, onsen-ui2

I'm currently making an hybrid application by using Angular2(RC6) and OnsenUI2.
 I've got a problem about displaying image by  tag. Here is my code.

```
 <div class="content">
    <div class="center" style="margin: 100px 0;">
        <img src="./images/logoTherapist.png" width="40%">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is the error I got. Though I set the project path to this image source, I cannot display any image.
If you have any solution, I'd like to know. Thanks.

Comment: Can you send more of your code since it's hard to tell with the sample you provided?
NOTE: Make sure your files are in the "www" folder, since the app has only access to that folder.

Comment: @user7461 Thank you for commenting. I've already solved this problem.